# NumberFormatter rounding unexpectedly

Tags: swift, swift3, nsnumberformatter

Here is a code I use for adding commas:

```
extension String
{
    func addCommas() -> String
    {
        var result = String(self)

        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
        let number = NSNumber(value:Float64(result)!)
        result = numberFormatter.string(from: number)

        return result!
    }
}
```

Then I set e.g. "1000".addCommas() then it returns fine "1,000" but when I set the number "1.1234".addCommas() then it returns "1.123" Seems it rounds the number. How to resolve the issue above?

Comment: So your question is not about adding commas. It's about `NumberFormatter` rounding values unexpectedly.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `NumberFormatter`. Specifically the section on rounding and on fraction digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using NumberFormater, something like this.

```
let value = 1000
let formater = NumberFormatter()
formater.numberStyle = .decimal
formater.groupingSeparator = ","
print(formater.string(from: NSNumber(integerLiteral: value)) ?? "Return nil value")
```

Apple docs are available [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/numberformatter)